# Status bar become black after another ViewController appears

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I have issue with Navigation Controller inside TabBarController. I have 5 view controllers and 3 of them have navigation bar. I need to make white status bars of all of this 3 VC. And i can do it with

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
```

But here is the problem. When i push another View Controller and return back my status bar again become black

Here is my code for every VC

1st VC:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupSearchBar()
    setupTableView()
    createAd()
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.text = "Library"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 35)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          // Always adopt a light interface style.
          overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
      }
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: label)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named:"settingsButton"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.action(sender:)))
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
}
```

2nd VC:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    configureSegmentsContainer()
    configurSegments()
    setupCollectionView()
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          // Always adopt a light interface style.
          overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
      }
    
}
```

and 3rd:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    setupTabelView()
    configure()
    setupNavBar()
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          // Always adopt a light interface style.
          overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
      }
}
```

What I am doing wrong and how i can fix it. PLS HELP

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
```

**Solution 2**

```
class BaseNavigationControllerDark: UINavigationController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
}
```

embed vc1 in BaseNavigationController and but not the other two just simple push vc2 or more

```
//replace this 
let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1) 
//to this
let vc = BaseNavigationControllerDark(rootViewController: vc1)
```

Comment: With this implementation status bar didn't became white even with 1st launch

Comment: I am edit my answer check now

Comment: I prefer is use Solution number 2

Comment: it doesn't work with my architecture

Comment: how you present your first vc

Comment: the first vc is the root of navigation controller right ?

Comment: first vc is initial VC, but its embed in TabBarController

Comment: add child in tab bar with base navigation controller not simple controller

Answer (score 0):

Try like this [image] i believe it will help you.

Comment: it's not helped